# Optimal way to pass list from Java (using JDBC) to Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server

I have read about a few ways to do this, but was wondering if anyone has actually seen differences in performance or knows of alternative methods.  The two ways I have seen are

1) Java sends a comma or space delimited list of values in a string which sql server parses out (can also use xml for this).  i.e '1,2,3'

2) Batch insert the values into a sql server table with an ID for the set of values, then run a sql query that works with the values in the table.

Comment: If possible it would be better if you can send a table valued parameter instead of a delimited string. If you have to send in a delimited string you have to split it in the sql side which is less than optimal. Here is an article that discusses splitters and provides some examples. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is curious the [tried and true splitstrings clr](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) is by far the best in my test cases.  About 5 times faster than the jdbc batch insert for large (> 1 million) number of inserts.

And about 15 times faster than inserting records one at a time.  Disclaimer: My performance tests were not rigorous.